# Hide parent element if all childrens are selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

My code is in jsfiddle.net/X23LG/1/

As per code when I select all the category of specific parent I want to hide particular parent
if any one of the child is activated then the parent element should also get activated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hide particular parent? Or, do you mean that when all children are checked it should also check the parent?

Comment: when all children are checked the parent should be disappeared or it should be made hidden when i activate any one or all child again parent should be visible

Comment: When the parent gets hidden, the children go with it :) also, when the parent checkbox is ticked, all children would get checked and then the parent disappears ... a bit odd ...

Comment: yes children should go with it

Comment: But if the children are hidden, how do you activate them again?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go man

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X23LG/18/)

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").not('.selectall').change(function () {
    $('.selectall').each(function(){
        var total = $(this).parent('div').siblings('ul').find('input').length;
        var selected = $(this).parent('div').siblings('ul').find('input:checked').length;
        if(selected >=1){$(this).attr('checked', true).parent('div').fadeOut();}else{$(this).attr('checked', false).parent('div').fadeIn();}
    });
});

$("input.selectall").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('ul').find('input').attr('checked', true);
        $(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
     }else{
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('ul').find('input').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).parent('div').fadeIn();
    }

});
```

Comment: Just let you know, your code can't uncheck the parent checbox manually at this moment

Comment: Correct...Unless there is a little more clarification from the op about the exact goal, this is what I thought he was going for.. Haha

Comment: @Felix I changed it though I still don't exactly know his end goal

Comment: Actually when i select  category1.1 ,category1.2,category1.3 the parent1 must be hidden becuse these selected categories are going to be deleted in my logic if again i activate any one of the category i.e  category1.1 or all categories than again parent1 must be visible this what I mean

Comment: ya its working but only the checkbox is disappearing i.e hidding but parentname with that checkbox in <li> tag is remaining there can you tell the the solution to hide the checkbox and corresponding parentname.thanks